# Fetching data from MSSQL

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I got an interface that sends (FROMDATE and TODATE) to the MSSQl and retrieves the selected details and after receiving them the data is shown on the grid.

I'm using the MVC.

This is the js script that I'm using.

```
$('body').on('submit', '#form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#btnSubmit').html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" style="font-size:14px"></i>  Please wait ....');
    $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);

    var fromdate = $('#PeriodFrom').val();
    var todate = $('#PeriodTo').val();

    if ($('#PeriodFrom').val() > $('#PeriodTo').val())
    {
        ToastMessage("To date cannot be less than From date ");
        return false;
    }

    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ReservationInquiries/ReservationInquery?fromdate=' + fromdate + '&todate=' + todate,

        dataType: 'JSON',
        method: 'GET',

        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" style="font-size:14px"></i>  Please wait ....');
            $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').html('Save');
            $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
        },
        success: function () {
            FillGrid();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

**url: '/ReservationInquiries/ReservationInquery?fromdate=' + fromdate + '&todate=' + todate,**
When the user picks the date range.By using the following  URL it sends the Fromdate and Todate toward the controller then the Service and then the Entry.

It returns backs ReservationNo and Name from MSQL.

So according to my program, everything is fetched to the model (the values which is fetched from MSQL).
As you can see when it redirects back I'm calling a function called **FillGrid();**in my js.

function FillGrid() is the function that I'm using to draw the grid in the HTML.

Even the data is fetched nothing is displayed on my grid is this wrong?
can anyone help me?

```
function FillGrid() {
    debugger;
    if ($('#grid').length == 1) {
        $('#grid tr').not(':first-child').remove();
        $.ajax({
            //url: '/ReservationInquiries/select?search=' + $('#txtSearch').val(),
            //dataType: 'JSON',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.grid').hide();
                $("#loadingProjects").show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                ShowGrid();
                $("#loadingProjects").hide();
            },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {

                debugger
                //var inquirieslist = JSON.stringify(data.InqueryList)

                $('#grid tr:not(:first)').empty();
                if (inquirieslist != null) {
                    $.each(inquirieslist, function (index, item) {

                        $('<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + item.ReservationNo  + '</td>' + 
                            '<td>' + item.Name + '</td>' + 
                            '</tr>').appendTo($('#grid'));

                    });

                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `inquirieslist` is string, but later you try to loop it. Are you looking for `JSON.parse()` to convert from string to object? JQuery has `dataType: "JSON"` param to auto-parse response as JSON

Comment: @Justinas Sorry my bad. It should have been a commented line.

Comment: If that is commented, then your `inquirieslist` is undefined